# Grant access to resource server with tokens generated by Resource server client key and secret - Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a AuthorizationServer and a ResourceServer configured using spring-boot, i have registered two dummy client using unique client-id and client-secret in oauth_client_details tables. I have configured one of these client in the ResourceServer providing the client-id and client-secret.Then i generate a token using the other key and secret and sent a api request with bearer token and it returned success which is not the expected behavior. I need to allow to send request with tokens generated by the application client key and secret. Could not found anything on the internet regarding this, your help is appreciated.

Below is the Code for Authorization Server

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore());
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

In the Resource server I have enabled @EnableResourceServer and added the relevant security configs in application.yml file

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/oauth/check_token
    client:
      client-id: mobile
      client-secret: pin
```

Note that I have generated the token using another registered client-key and a secret, but still I can call successfully to above resource server using that token.

Thank you,
Rajith

Comment: @ThomasAndolf apologies if question was not clear, I have added the code, please check if you can help

Comment: and the dubug logs say?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf  Nothing it's not giving an error.

Comment: clientId and client-secret has nothing to do with the resource server. It is only used when calling the authorization server to get issued a token. I think you a misconception of what the clientId and secret is used for.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf correct me if i am wrong, we can have multiple client id secrets registered, we issue a token using one client id and secret then we used that token to call a resource of another client id and a secret and it got success. Is this a valid scenario

Comment: No, client id is only used to identify which client that wants to get issued a token from the authorization serever. The token itself contains no info about what client. And the client id is ignored by the resource server.

Comment: client id is only used to validate who is calling the authorization server when wanting to get issued a token. nothing more

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thank you very much for the clarification. I found that I we could do this configuring a resourceId in the ResourceServer.

Answer (score 0):

After a day surfing through google I found that we could use resourceId to cater the above scenario.

- Register a client (save client-key,secret in the oauth_client_details with a resourceId or multiple resource Id's)
- Generate a token with using the registered client-key and secret, this token contains a "aud" field which represents the resource ID we saved in the database.
- Below is a check_token response returned from a generated token

eg :

```
{
  "aud": [
    "mobile",
    "web",
  ],
  "user_name": "user1",
  "scope": [
    "READ"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "language": "ENGLISH",
  "exp": 1580028351,
  "client_id": "client_1"
}
```

- Now in the ResourceServer you need to check that the provided token contains this resource ID. See the below example code, it checks whether the provided bearer token has a aud with mobile, otherwise the request will be forbidden.

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "mobile";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

}
```

That's it guys, Please let me know if you can add more to this. Thank you @Thomas Andolf for the clarifications.

Comment: first i must ask, that is a json web token? because i see no subject

Comment: @ThomasAndolf no it's a bearer token

Comment: then what is the posted json?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf that's the check_token response.